# Discrepancy between closed form solution and numerical solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following differential equation

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{1}{\alpha t}x(1-x) \,,\,x\in [1,20) \tag 1$$
The solution on this interval  by taking $x(1) = 0.9999$ is given by

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{1+0.0001\exp\left( \frac{\ln(t) - \ln t(1)}{ \alpha}\right)}  ~. \tag 2$$

Now if $\alpha = 0.2$, then $x(20) = \lim_{x\to 20^-} x(t)$, so that $$ x(20) =\frac{1}{1+0.0001\exp\left( \frac{\ln(20)}{ 0.2}\right)}\approx 0.0031 ~. \tag 3$$

On the other hand discretizing (1) using Euler approximation yields 
$$ x(t_i)= x(t_{i-1}) - \frac{1}{\alpha t_{i-1}}x(t_{i-1}) (1-x(t_{i-1}) )\Delta t_i~. \tag 4$$ Then
$$ x(20) = 0.9999 - \frac{1}{0.2 \cdot 1} 0.9999\cdot (1-0.9999)\cdot (20-1) \approx  0.9904  \tag 5$$

I know the Euler approximation is very conservative but this result is puzzling. I'm sure I'm missing something but I don't know what. Why is there such a "big" discrepancy between (3) and (5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closed form solution I obtained from this is: $$ x(t) = \frac C{t^{1/\alpha} + C}$$

Note that there are several other equivalent forms that one could use, one of which is the form in Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer, and I think yours may also be correct, although I haven't verified it.  Anyway, with $x(1) = 0.9999$ and $\alpha = 0.2$, we have $$ x(t) = \frac{9999}{t^5 + 9999}.$$

Here we get $x(20) \approx 0.0031$, just like you did.

With Euler's method you appear to be using a very large step size of $\Delta t_i = 19$.  I think this is what's causing the problems.  **We want our step sizes to be very small when using numerical methods.**

When I run Euler's method through a custom spreadsheet with $\Delta t = 0.5$, I get $x(20) \approx 0.0289$.  Better, but still not great.

When I run it with $\Delta t = 0.1$, I get $x(20) \approx 0.0056$.

With $\Delta t = 0.05$, I get $x(20) \approx 0.0042$.

Finally, with $\Delta t = 0.001$, I get $x(20) \approx 0.0031$.

So overall the problem appears to be that your $\Delta t$ is just too large.

---

Picture of part of spreadsheet:

[image: Euler's method spreadsheet pic]

To create the spreadsheet:

1. Place labels in row $1$ (or don't)
2. In cell $A2$, enter `1`
3. In cell $B2$, enter `0.9999`
4. In cell $C2$, enter `0.05` (or whatever your desired $\Delta t$ is)
5. In cell $A3$, enter this **exactly**: `=A2+C$2`
6. In cell $B3$, enter this **exactly**: `=B2-1/(0.2*A2)*B2*(1-B2)*C$2`
7. Copy cells $A3$ and $B3$ and paste them into cells $A4$ and $B4$, and cells $A5$ and $B5$, etc., as far down as you'd like to go.

As Winther pointed out in the comments, you'll need to perform multiple steps to get to $t = 20$.

Also, try doing just one step with $\Delta t = 19$.  When I do that I get $x(20) \approx 0.9904$.  More evidence that these methods are intended to be used with very small step sizes.

Compare these two plots of $x(t)$, $0 \le t \le 300$ (technically the second one goes to $t=305$ because of the step size) obtained from Euler's method, one with $\Delta t = 0.01$ and one with $\Delta t = 19$, and note the large discrepancy for $t \le 150$.

[image]

Compare also with the plot of the analytic solution using desmos.com:

[image]

Comment: What version of Euler's method are you using. I'm not able to get your results with my equation (4) . for example with $\Delta t = 0.1$, using (4), I get $x(20) \approx  0.99985 $

Comment: @L.bronze Let me guess: you simply substituted $\Delta t = 0.1$ in your formula (4) for $x(20)$? This means you are just taking one single step so what you have found is $x(1+0.1)$ not $x(20)$. You need to take $n$ steps using this equation *until*  $t_n = 20$. Since $t_n = 1+n\Delta t$ this means $n = 190$ steps for $\Delta t = 0.1$.

Comment: @L.bronze, see my update for steps on creating the spreadsheet.

Comment: @tilper Thanks . So basically, the problem lies with the one step I chose.

Comment: @winther  Yes, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @tilper  A general question about the Euler method. Is it possible to use unequal step sizes? If so, when might one be advised to do so as opposed to equal step sizes.

Comment: @L.bronze, it's possible.  There's the concept of [adaptive stepsize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_stepsize), where we have a maximum error tolerance in mind and the procedure automatically adjusts the $\Delta t$ to stay within that tolerance level.  See also [this](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/math/vble.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write $$\frac{dx}{x(1-x)}=-\frac{1}{\alpha t}dt$$ the solution should be $$x(t)=\frac{1}{e^{c_1} t^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is my closed-form solution wrong?

Comment: @L.bronze, your closed-form solution appears to be correct.  See my recently undeleted answer.  The problem is likely your very large $\Delta t_i$.